# angular2 and firebase with angularfire2 how to iterate over list in typescript

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

items: FirebaseListObservable;

this.items = af.database.list(path);

In template no issue e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
</div>
```

In typescript how do iterate of the values returned as  FirebaseListObservable?

e.g.

```
for (var _i = 0; _i < this.items.length; _i++) {

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your component you need to subscribe:

```
this.items = af.database.list(path)
this.items.subscribe(items => items.forEach(item => console.log(item)));
```